# Highlighting text in the default Windows CHM viewer

Tags: windows, linux, macos, chm

How do I set up the default [CHM reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) in Windows to highlight text? Is this even possible?

When I read ebooks I need to highlight some of the text and it's just not there in the default CHM program.

Or would I be better off looking for another CHM viewer? If that's the case I'm best up for something that would work on Windows, Linux and Mac if that's the alternative.

Answer (score 11):

I just found [Kchmviewer](http://www.kchmviewer.net/). It looks really good with:

- Windows, Mac and Linux.
- Easy navigation: ctrl + left or right arrow keys to navigate next or previous sections
- Tabbed interface
- Ability to change font size
- Allows you to add your own persistent bookmarks
- Excellent search even for files without and index
- Highlights text just fine

I've installed it on Windows 7 64-bit and it works great:

[image]

Comment: where does it highlight the text -- I'm talking about permanent highlighting.

Answer (score 8):

There is a handy Firefox add-on called [CHM Reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/3235) which allows you to open CHM files within Firefox:

[image]

To achieve the highlighting support you're after you can use [TextMarker!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/559), another useful add-on:

[image]

Of course, it will work on any platform with Firefox installed.

Comment: A user of the add-on made a comment regarding that actually! - *Great. Just does exactly what's needed. Pages or paragraphs of text with highlights can be saved perfectly with the UnMHT extension, including the highlights.* very cool indeed :)