# What's a good CHM file viewer for (Fedora) Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, chm

I installed GnoCHM and it keeps on crashing on my Fedora installation so I'm looking for better alternatives. Please only suggest those that you've used.

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/questions/96565/best-free-chm-viewer

Comment: Yup, I saw that. Please don't close this as my questions if for Linux only. That question pertains to multiple-OSes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks liks [chmsee](http://code.google.com/p/chmsee) is working nicely.

Comment: I'm going with this one since it hasn't crashed for more than a week.

Comment: ChmSee is not being developed anymore.

Answer (score 7):

I regularly use [xchm](http://xchm.sourceforge.net/), so far without any issues. It's part of at least Debian.

It shows images, the table of contents to the left and supports printing.

Comment: xchm by far is the best one. it opens up fast and one can print!

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend "Chmsee". Easy to install, light weight and not heavy compared to Okular which i got by default with FC 14 Link to download Chmsee

[DOwnload Chmsee](http://code.google.com/p/chmsee/downloads/detail?name=chmsee-1.3.0.tar.gz)

Comment: ChmSee is not being developed any more.

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed [kchmviewer](http://www.ulduzsoft.com/linux/kchmviewer/). It doesn't require many dependencies (it can be integrated with KDE, but doesn't require its packages). From its description:

> The main advantage of kchmviewer is the best support for non-English languages. Unlike other viewers, kchmviewer in most cases is able to correctly detect the chm file encoding and show it. It correctly shows the index and table of context in Russian, Spanish, Romanian, Korean, Chinese and Arabic help files, and with new search engine is able to search in any chm file no matter what language it is written.

I've found this package simply by making `dnf search chm` - try your own system's package manager's search and find available packages.

Answer (score 0):

Never used a CHM viewer. I always extract it to html+images so I can use any web browser. chmlib has a tool for that.